# virtual machines on LAN : speed and bandwidth questions

Tags: debian, virtualbox, bandwidth

I would like to get some advices on VM servers.

Indeed, instead of creating again and again the same VM in virtualbox, I am wondering if having a virtual machines server would not be better, but I have no experience on it.

For now, I have some computers (a laptop with windows 10, a mini-pc with debian 9) and openmediavault (a nas oriented debian distribution). In fact, I got the idea of a VM server thanks to the nas distrib : there is a virtualbox plugin, yet is is no more maintained and I was not able to run a VM from it.

I tried to enable display remote in virtualbox running on windows, and using remmina on the desktop on debian I was able to get the VM screen(a fedora installation). But it was very slow, and not adapted to a daily use. The desktop is connected to the LAN by ethernet but the laptop by wifi. I assume connecting it via ethernet should speed up the connection.

So I ask you some questions :
- should I use an ethernet wire for both computers? If so, will a enough good connection possible? Is it even thinkable to try to connect a VM server to the LAN and to get VMs available for an other computer in the network? 
- What is the hardware/software to use for such a server?  Is a real NAS required?
- do I need 1Gb/s broadband over power line wire of do 300Mb/S ones suffice?

Comment: I got lost in the question. What is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

A few things.... not exactly an "answer" but not really a comment, and I think it will help you.  If you re-read the question guidelines asking a better question can help as well, since you are more likely to get a direct and correct answer...

Wired is better than wireless, almost always.  If you must use wireless, minimize the number of clients - don't be "well, I have my printer on wireless, may as well put everything else since I have the access point set up, etc".  Even with equal theoretical speeds, wireless is more like using a hub instead of a switch - the more clients, the more congestion, the worse performance.

X11 over SSH (only way I've done remote desktops for Linux, and I don't do Windows) is tolerable on a 1mb connection, works OK on 10mb ethernet, is just fine on 100mb ethernet, and on a gigabit network you may as well be sitting at the machine just about, so I don't think it is your overall bandwidth.

Depending on what OSes are in play (both on remote end and local) remote desktop may be network designed like the X11 protocol, or it may be 3rd party and just sending the equivalent of lots of JPEGS back to the viewing end, this uses a LOT more bandwidth.  If you are using Linux on the remote end, forward X11 over SSH.  If you are using Windows on the remote end, use the proper RDP tools - it will work better since it will be more integrated.  Or consider setting up a Windows Terminal Server.

As to a VM server... the correct way would be to use a bare metal hypervisor (type 1 hypervisor) on a sufficiently beefy machine or cluster to handle your VMs.  If you can't do that and must use a Type2 (like VirtualBox) then you want a host OS that takes as few resources as possible - basically, run Linux as the host.